# TypeError: mod is not a function error in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I upgraded Swiper from version 9.3.2 to 10.2.0, and now I'm encountering a **TypeError: mod is not a function** error in reactJs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After various tests, I realized that in the new version, we need to change module addressing from

```
import { EffectFade } from 'swiper';
```

to

```
import { EffectFade } from 'swiper/modules';
```

If you still have an error, try this way.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
```

Answer (score 2):

Only swiper version

> swiper: "8.4.2"

and below accepts the import of modules in the `import { Navigation } from "swiper";`
format. You would have to add the /modules suffix like this `ìmport { EffectFade } from "swiper/modules";` for the newest versions or downgrade your swiperjs to suit your preference.

See more documentation [swiperjs modules import for newer versions](https://swiperjs.com/get-started)